# An update with multiple conditions. SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, case

I have a table...

```
ProjectID    UserID    RoleID
101          1         10
101          2         10
102          2         10
102          3         10
103          1         10
```

Currently there is only one type of Role, role '10', but I'm wanting to add a new role, role '11', which will act as a lead. So any project that has a user with the role of '10', should have a lead. The user chosen to be lead will be based on a priorty list, in this example we'll say the order is 1, 2, 3.

Expected result...

```
ProjectID    UserID    RoleID
101          1         11
101          2         10
102          2         11
102          3         10
103          1         11
```

Comment: And what you've done for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can figure out which user has the highest priority by using `row_number()`.  SQL Server let's you do this in an updatable CTE, so the query looks like this:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by projectid
                                order by (case when userid = 1 then 1
                                               when userid = 2 then 2
                                               when userid = 3 then 3
                                               else 4
                                          end
                                         )
                               ) as PriorityForLead
      from table t
     )
update toupdate
    set RoleId = 11
    where PriorityForLead = 1;
```

Comment: So while I was unable to get this to work correctly, I can understand the logic of it. However, this would appear to only make the update where userid = 1, which does not meet my expected result.

Comment: @DougMocniak  . . . You don't seem to understand the logic of it at all.  This will update the first user on each project, based on the rules you specified for prioritization.

Comment: @DougMocniak - The `PriorityForLead = 1` does not only update userid = 1 it updates based on the first sequential number in an incrementing number which is ordered by userid.  Run it without the update and view the results

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm gettin the error of "missing keyword". I apologize for my ignorance.

Comment: @DougMocniak . . . I left the `end` off of the `case`.  Here is a working fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fa2e16/5.

Comment: ^ I just figured that out as well. Thanks for your help!