# In Oracle SQL, how do I UPDATE columns specified by a priority list?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

So, I've already had this question answered already, but now I need the Oracle SQL solution. (See: [An update with multiple conditions. SQL 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626401/an-update-with-multiple-conditions-sql-2008))

But to run through it again..

Below is the current table "table1".

```
ProjectID    UserID    RoleID
101          1         10
101          2         10
102          2         10
102          3         10
103          1         10
```

Currently there is only one type of Role, role '10', but I'm wanting to add a new role, role '11', which will act as a lead. So any project that has a user with the role of '10', should have a lead. The user chosen to be lead will be based on a priorty list, in this example we'll say the order is 1, 2, 3.

Expected result...

```
ProjectID    UserID    RoleID
101          1         11
101          2         10
102          2         11
102          3         10
103          1         11
```

I was unable to get the WITH clause, from the previous solution, to work properly, as from what I have learned, Oracle does not take a FROM in a WITH clause.

Here is the working query that I essentially need to use in an UPDATE, and update roleid to 11 where PriorityForLead is = 1.

```
select t.*, row_number() over (partition by projectid
                               order by (case when userid = 1 then 1
                                              when userid = 2 then 2
                                              when userid = 3 then 3
                                              else 4
                                         end )
                               ) as PriorityForLead
from table1 t
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update table1 t1
   set roleid = 11
 where roleid = 10 and
       (case when userid = 1 then 1 when userid = 2 then 2 when userid = 3 then 3 else 4 end) =
         (select min(case when userid = 1 then 1 when userid = 2 then 2 when userid = 3 then 3 else 4 end)
            from table1
           where projectid = t1.projectid);
```

EDIT:

```
SQL> create table table1 (projectid number, userid number, roleid number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into table1 values (101, 1, 10);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into table1 values (101, 2, 10);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into table1 values (102, 2, 10);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into table1 values (102, 3, 10);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into table1 values (103, 1, 10);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from table1;

 PROJECTID     USERID     ROLEID
---------- ---------- ----------
       101          1         10
       101          2         10
       102          2         10
       102          3         10
       103          1         10

SQL> update table1 t1
  2     set roleid = 11
  3   where roleid = 10 and
  4         (case when userid = 1 then 1 when userid = 2 then 2 when userid = 3 then 3 else 4 end) = 
  5           (select min(case when userid = 1 then 1 when userid = 2 then 2 when userid = 3 
then 3 else 4 end)
  5                     from table1
  6                    where projectid = t1.projectid);

3 rows updated.

SQL> select * from table1;           

 PROJECTID     USERID     ROLEID
---------- ---------- ----------
       101          1         11
       101          2         10
       102          2         11
       102          3         10
       103          1         11
```

Comment: I believe this is due to the dummy user_id data being equal to the min number. In the real scenario it would look like... "userid = (select min(case when userid = 3172 then 1 when userid = 2953 then 2 else 3 end)"

Comment: Updated again. Just replaced `userid =` with the whole `case` expression.

Comment: Great! I figured another case was required, didn't get to play with it again. Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the 3 columns provided are the compound primary key for this table, the query below should be a correct conversion to Oracle.

```
update t
    set RoleId = 11
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM 
(select t.*,
                 row_number() over (partition by projectid
                                    order by (case when userid = 1 then 1
                                                   when userid = 2 then 2
                                                   when userid = 3 then 3
                                                   else 4
                                              end
                                             )
                                   ) as PriorityForLead
          from table t) toupdate
                  WHERE toupdate.PriorityForLead = 1
                  AND t.ProjectID = toupdate.ProjectID
                  AND t.UserID = toupdate.UserID
                  AND t.RoleID = toupdate.RoleId);
```

Comment: The table does not have a primary key.

Comment: That's pretty weird. Not even a compound primary key?

Comment: Just the 3 columns that I provided.

Comment: Edited my answer with the knowledge that these columns form a compound pk

Comment: "table or view does not exist"

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to change all the `t`'s to your actual table?